# How to load Factories for Embedded Models (Mongoid - Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, factory-bot

I am using Mongoid in my Rails application, consider i have the below fields in a class named **"Post"** with below structure

```
class UserPost

  include Mongoid::Document
  field :post, type: String
  field :user_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
  embeds_many :comment, :class_name => "Comment"

  validates_presence_of :post, :user_id

end
```

-

```
class Comment

  include Mongoid::Document
  field :commented_user_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
  field :comment, type: String

  embedded_in :user_post, :class_name => "UserPost"

end
```

This model works perfect when inserting values.

But now i am working on writing test for this model, i am using Factory girl to load test data. I am confused with how i can plot out model fields for **"UserPost"** model under
`/spec/factories/user_posts.rb`.

I tried with below format, but its not working (only some fields are added for example)

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user_post do
    id Moped::BSON::ObjectId("50ffd609253ff1bfb2000002")
    post "Good day..!!"
    user_id Moped::BSON::ObjectId("50ffd609253ff1bfb2000002")
    comment :comment
  end

  factory :comment do
    id Moped::BSON::ObjectId("50ffd609253ff1bfb2000002")
  end

end
```

Comment: why do you hardcode ids?

Comment: its for example.. how should i define factory without hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is building objects with associations. We solved this problem using `ignore` block to lazily build associations.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  # User factory
  factory :user do
    # ...
  end

  # UserPost factory
  factory :user_post do

    # nothing in this block gets saved to DB
    ignore do
      user { create(:user) } # call User factory
    end

    post "Good day..!!"

    # get id of user created earlier
    user_id { user.id }

    # create 2 comments for this post
    comment { 2.times.collect { create(:comment) } }
  end
end

# automatically creates a user for the post
FactoryGirl.create(:user_post)

# manually overrides user for the post
user = FactoriGirl.create(:user)
FactoryGirl.create(:user_post, user: user)
```

One fix... In the `:user_post` factory, you should create an array of `Comment` objects for `UserPost.comment` because of `embeds_many`. Not just a single one.